# Cannot send document to cloud reader

Tags: kindle, amazon, send-to-kindle, kindle-cloud-reader, website

I "sent" a website to Kindle with the Chrome plugin.  The sent page shows in "Manage your Content" but I can't find it in the cloud reader.  I even added to a collection and ensured it was sent to a device as well.

Is there some "good" way to open docs from "manage your content" I'm not seeing, or some other ways to search the Amazon cloud reader?

The option in "send to devices" for the cloud reader is greyed out.

Comment: this might be a bug around sync